# Food for 400+km ride? (in single session)

Tags: nutrition, long-distance

Last September I did a 400km trip in ~23 hours.
For food I went through 20 cliff bars. My stomach was pretty upset with all of those.

This year I wanna try 500km.

I am looking for an alternative food source, something consumable in large quantities and friendly on the stomach. Yet fits into my back pack. (Although stopping 1-2 at a grocery store would be Ok also).

I was considering making energy drinks and bring 3L container with me in my backpack with straw that goes to mouth. But, erm, can you get by on liquid drinks alone?

Is there any other food that is friendly on the stomach, consumable while cycling and has a lot of energy to sustain ongoing high performance?

(I was going through ~700 calories an hour, it was about 12,000 calories total).

Comment: You need a variety of stuff, not just Cliff bars.  With a balance of carbs that register across the glycolic index scale, a little bit of fat, a bit more protein (but not a whole lot), and some fiber (but again, not too much).

Comment: This vid might be helpful - [The Musette - What Do Pro Cyclists Eat?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnKWkvBMn3s&index=799&list=UUuTaETsuCOkJ0H_GAztWt0Q). It has all the usual bars and gels, but also interesting "fresh" concoctions that are prepared each day from "real" ingredients. I think it would be useful to plan some proper meal stops, though, if you are able.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. Unfortunately, questions like this are [too broad](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) for our format. There are some related questions to the right which might be helpful. [The Velodrome](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/214/the-velodrome) would also be a great place to discuss good riding foods. It's much more free form.

Comment: @PeteH I think your link is wrong. It goes to the Tour de France day 14 overview.  Did you mean this video? http://youtu.be/Fvy43QrIW5I Not being a racer, I would have recommended any of meals over gel packs and cliff bars. ;)

Comment: Thanks @Claus. Actually it was [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rolr6fsZJtk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rolr6fsZJtk), but YouTube is littered with them. It was mainly to try and give some ideas over and above the ubiquitous gels and bars

Comment: Cycling gels can help, they're small and powerful but not very filling.  You need to mix it up with some nut bars, fresh fruit, and plenty of water.  Have a decent big breakfast before you go.... muesli with milk would be ideal, as would porridge.    A camelback drink bag might be best rather than bidons/bottles.